# How to colorize a drawable without affecting the transparent areas of the image?

Tags: android, drawable, colorize

In most graphic programs like Photoshop and Gimp there is a colorize function so you can easily color a gray scale image with a color of your choice. I want to do the same thing with an image in my Android application. I have been looking into the setColorFilter function. This is what I tried.

```
ImageView border = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
int color = Color.parseColor("#F57F17"); // the color to use
border.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY);
```

This does exactly what I need. The only problem is that it also colors the transparent areas in the image. I want the transparent areas to stay transparent.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for SRC_ATOP:

```
ImageView border = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
int color = Color.parseColor("#F57F17"); // the color to use
border.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: I tried that already. It does leave the transparent areas transparent, but it just overlays the actual image with the color. In other words I lose the different intensities of the original gray scale image.

Answer (score 0):

Colorize the drawable then set it back.
I do this with binding and an adapter to override image colors of drawables.

Example, I change the drawable color based on selected status below:

```
  @JvmStatic
@BindingAdapter("backgroundDrawableChange")
fun backgroundDrawableChange(view: RelativeLayout, isSelected: Boolean){
    var bgDrawable: LayerDrawable = view.background as LayerDrawable
    var shape: GradientDrawable =  bgDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.shapeId) as GradientDrawable
    shape.setColor(Color.parseColor((if (isSelected) YACustomPreference.getInstance(view.context).getPrimaryColorHex() else YACustomPreference.getInstance(view.context).getWhite())))
}
```

Here is another example of overriding menu item colors when you need more dynamic control.

```
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_info_fragment, menu)
    try{
        //get drawable filter, change color, and reassign
        var filterDrawable = menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter).icon
        filterDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(filterDrawable)
        DrawableCompat.setTint(filterDrawable, Color.parseColor(YACustomPreference.getInstance(activity!!).getPrimaryTextColorHex()))
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter).icon = filterDrawable

        //get searchview drawable change color and setup listener
        mSearchView = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)?.actionView as SearchView
        mSearchView?.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
        val searchDrawableImageView = mSearchView?.findViewById<View>(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_button) as ImageView
        val searchDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_search_action, null)
        DrawableCompat.setTint(searchDrawable!!, Color.parseColor(YACustomPreference.getInstance(activity!!).getPrimaryTextColorHex()))
        searchDrawableImageView.setImageDrawable(searchDrawable)
    }catch (ex: Exception){
        A35Log.e(TAG, "Error updating SearchView drawable icon")
    }

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}
```

That should hopefully help you get what you are doing across the finish line.
Happy Coding.

Comment: I translated your code into Java:

    `ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Drawable filterDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(img.getDrawable());
    DrawableCompat.setTint(filterDrawable, Color.parseColor("#F57F17"));
    img.setImageDrawable(filterDrawable);`

But it gives me the same result as:

    `border.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);`

I lose the different intensities of the original gray scale image since the actual image is replaced with a flat color.

Comment: Have you considered switching to Vector Graphics? That is primarily what I work with and I don't have any issues with the above code. Each customer chooses their own colors so I override the Vector graphics by using the above code and it works perfectly, but I haven't done it with PNGs or JPGs really.

Comment: I never worked with vector graphics before but I want to try your suggestion. So now I'm learning about those vector graphics. Thank you.

Comment: You won't regret it. 1 drawable for all devices is so much nicer than managing all the folders and duplicate images of different resolutions. Most commonly you will find SVG graphics. You can import 1 at a time into Android, or you can use this tool that works great (they aren't supporting anymore, but it works) http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/ to convert to android drawable vectors. They are more efficient subsets of SVG graphics basically.